# SQL continuous database blocking for EJB timers scheduler

Tags: java, sql, jvm, ejb, websphere

We have a Java enterprise based application which is running on **IBM WebSphere servers** ( running on cluster environment). **Our application uses EJB timers scheduler** (Timers in WebSphere are used to schedule tasks and events, such as a business process, at certain times throughout the day. Timers and their associated events are stored in the EJB container.) functionality.

EJB creates its own table based on scheduler configuration.

From past few days we are getting continuous blocking alert for our timer services -
**Below queries are continuously blocked** -
SELECT ME_UUID,INC_UUID,VERSION,MIGRATION_VERSION FROM SIBOWNER WHERE NOT ME_UUID='LOCK'
SELECT 1 FROM SIBOWNER (TABLOCKX)

**We have restarted our websphere, JVM nodes to make sure fresh timers are created, but after 4-5 hrs of restart DB blocking starts reappearing.**

Need your help, if any of you have faced similar situation and found remedy of it.

Comment: My general advice is to get rid of Websphere.

Comment: My general advice is to have a nice cold beer, but I am curious as to why a `select` should block.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your servers are clustered.  Are you scheduling persistent EJB timers at the cluster level as well (one timer for the cluster, where all servers are pointing at the same database tables), or at the server level (each server uses different database tables for storing the EJB persistent timer data)?  If the latter, you may be ending up with the same timer logic running on all the servers at once, which could be a source of lock contention.  Also, I should point out that persistent EJB timers (persistent is the default) do not disappear when the server shuts down, because the record of them persists in the database, and so if you have initialization logic to "make sure fresh timers are created", you could be ending up with duplicates that compete with each other for the database.  There are a lot of ways that EJB timers can be used, and more detail about your configuration, the types of timers, how you schedule them, and all of the transactional operations that you perform within them (and outside of them upon the same data) would be needed to properly diagnose this.  This is the best guess I can offer lacking that level of detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response, EJB timers are at the cluster level.

Comment: Is that be the case, when connection was lost from one of node for swift period of time ?